# Receiving file from Xmpp

Tags: xmpp, chat

I am using Xmpp framework for a chat Application. I can able to send file through xmppOutgoingFileTransfer Obj.

But xmppIncomingFileTransfer Obj for receiving image is not working for me. Means it doesn't enter in to delegate method "didSucceedWithData" Method.

Please share the solution

Answer (score 0):

For transfer images and videos you have to upload this on your server and after complete this upload process you have to send this(Upload video/image) link to user. So user can easily download from that particular link.